# java.io.FileNotFoundException when running datomic ensure-transactor

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, datomic

I'm trying to learn datomic, and finding that the datomic setup and provisioning process has a very high learning curve.

One bizarre problem that I'm having -- which I'm hoping is due to some stupid mistake -- is that when I try to run `datomic ensure-transactor` I get a file not found error for the properties file.

You'll have to take my word for it that the file exists. I've even opened up all the permissions on the file in case this was a permissions problem.

My properties file looks like this (with license redacted etc) -- I'm attempting to provision a setup for a **local** instance of dynamodb. I've also installed dyanmodb-local using brew (`brew install dynamodb-local`):

```
################################################################

protocol=ddb-local
host=localhost
port=4334



################################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html

license-key=[license here]



################################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html
# DynamoDB storage settings

aws-dynamodb-table=datemo

# See http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#ddb_region
# aws-dynamodb-region=us-east-1

# To use DynamoDB Local, change the protocol (above) to ddb-local.
# Comment out aws-dynamodb-region, and instead use aws-dynamodb-override-endpoint
aws-dynamodb-override-endpoint=localhost:8080



################################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html
# This role has read and write access to storage and
# is used by the transactor to read and write data. Optionally,
# this role also has write access to an S3 bucket used for log
# storage and to CloudWatch for metrics, if those features are
# enabled.
# (Can be auto-generated by bin/datomic ensure-transactor.)

aws-transactor-role=



################################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html
# This role has read-only access to storage and
# is used by peers to read data.
# (Can be auto-generated by bin/datomic ensure-transactor.)

aws-peer-role=



################################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/capacity.html


# Recommended settings for -Xmx4g production usage.
# memory-index-threshold=32m
# memory-index-max=512m
# object-cache-max=1g

# Recommended settings for -Xmx1g usage, e.g. dev laptops.
memory-index-threshold=32m
memory-index-max=256m
object-cache-max=128m



## OPTIONAL ####################################################


# Set to false to disable SSL between the peers and the transactor.
# Default: true
# encrypt-channel=true

# Data directory is used for dev: and free: storage, and
# as a temporary directory for all storages.
# data-dir=data

# Transactor will log here, see bin/logback.xml to configure logging.
# log-dir=log

# Transactor will write process pid here on startup
# pid-file=transactor.pid



## OPTIONAL ####################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/storage.html
# Memcached configuration.

# memcached=host:port,host:port,...
# memcached-username=datomic
# memcached-password=datomic



## OPTIONAL ####################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/capacity.html


# Soft limit on the number of concurrent writes to storage.
# Default: 4, Miniumum: 2
# write-concurrency=4

# Soft limit on the number of concurrent reads to storage.
# Default: 2 times write-concurrency, Miniumum: 2
# read-concurrency=8



## OPTIONAL ####################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/aws.html
# Optional settings for rotating logs to S3
# (Can be auto-generated by bin/datomic ensure-transactor.)

# aws-s3-log-bucket-id=



## OPTIONAL ####################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/aws.html
# Optional settings for Cloudwatch metrics.
# (Can be auto-generated by bin/datomic ensure-transactor.)

# aws-cloudwatch-region=

# Pick a unique name to distinguish transactor metrics from different systems.
# aws-cloudwatch-dimension-value=your-system-name



## OPTIONAL ####################################################
# See http://docs.datomic.com/ha.html


# The transactor will write a heartbeat into storage on this interval.
# A standby transactor will take over if it sees the heartbeat go 
# unwritten  for 2x this interval. If your transactor load leads to 
# long gc pauses, you can increase this number to prevent the standby 
# transactor from unnecessarily taking over during a long gc pause.
# Default: 5000, Miniumum: 5000
# heartbeat-interval-msec=5000



## OPTIONAL ####################################################


# The transactor will use this partition for new entities that
# do not explicitly specify a partition.
# Default: :db.part/user
# default-partition=:db.part/user
```

If there's anyone out there that could set me straight, it'd be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here turns out to be that you **must** run `ensure-transactor` from the root director of the datomic package. This is apparently true for most of (but not all) datomic scripts. It seems to pertain in particular to one-off scripts like `ensure-transactor` that you'd run once.